Swagger JSDoc not displaying example value with response code 200
I am using swagger-jsdoc to document my API. I have a route that retrieves a list of admin users, and I have defined the response schema and example value for a successful response (code 200). However, the example value is not being displayed in the Swagger UI.
Here is my swagger-jsdoc configuration for the route:
JavaScript
/**
* @swagger
* /api/v1/admin-users:
*   get:
*     summary: Get all admin users
*     description: Get all admin users
*     tags: [Admin Users]
*     security:
*       - Bearer: []
*     responses:
*       200:
*         description: Success
*         content:
*           application/json:
*             schema:
*               type: object
*               properties:
*                 totalRecords:
*                   type: integer
*                   example: 1
*                 currentPage:
*                   type: integer
*                   example: 1
*                 totalPages:
*                   type: integer
*                   example: 10
*                 result:
*                   type: array
*                   items:
*                     type: object
*                     properties:
*                       id:
*                         type: string
*                         example: "605c72efb87c4e2e2d3b1b70"
*                       username:
*                         type: string
*                         example: "admin_user"
*                       email:
*                         type: string
*                         example: "admin@example.com"
*       401:
*         description: Unauthorized
*       404:
*         description: Not Found
*       500:
*         description: Internal Server Error
*/
    

Additional information:

swagger-jsdoc version:
"swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.8"


Swagger UI version:
"swagger-ui-express": "^5.0.1"



Current Swagger UI:

I have included the example property for each property within the response schema, but the example values are not showing up in the Swagger UI.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there something wrong with my swagger-jsdoc configuration?

Is your OpenAPI definition openapi: 3.0.x or swagger: '2.0'?

Thank @Helen configure openapi: 3.0 and working fine.
